# Ошибка кросдоменного POST запроса на angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

Отправляем запрос таким кодом:

```
$scope.updateProjects = function () {
    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    $http.post($scope.api+'api/v2/projects-advanced',  JSON.stringify($scope.request), config)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.projects = response.data.projects;
        });
};
```

На сервере (PHP,Laravel 5):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

В консоле ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что самое главное при заголовке:
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Все хорошо работает но на этот раз мне нужно передать даные не в "x-www-form-urlencoded", а в json.

Comment: Покажите заголовки, которые пришли в ответе на запрос с ошибкой.

Comment: @IgorGolovin 
Решил проблему, перешел на 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с CORS это обычно проблема на сервере, а не на клиенте. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045413/laravel-5-angularjs-cross-domain-cors) рассмотрена похожая на вашу проблема